# Detect when user hits start of view in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I've set listener :

```
                gridView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                    Log.v("","ScrollY" +gridView.getScrollY());
                    Log.v("","ScrollX" + gridView.getScrollX());
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // pageNumber = gridElementsCount
                    adapter.setFirstVisibleItem(firstVisibleItem);
                    adapter.setVisibleItemCount(visibleItemCount);

                    if(gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition()==0){
                        mContainerView.setIsOnTop(true);
                    } else mContainerView.setIsOnTop(false);

                }
            });
```

And I need to know when user after scrolling hits top of view. `getFirstVisiblePosition()` isn't good because it sets to `0` at the half of the scroll.

Comment: Can't you use the `gridView.getScrollY()` like you do in onSCrollStateChanged?

Comment: it always return 0, Log.v was just to check this

Comment: Maybe you can do something with view.getChildAt(0).getTop() to determine if it is scrolled entirely

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html) it would seem that `firstVisibleItem` is the index of the first item visible. By that logic when it is 0 then you should be at the top of the list, since the first item in the list should have an index of 0.

Comment: Yep, that's true but it switches to 0 when is on half of gridView cell, not only at very top of it. There seem to be no solution.